# SqlTableAdapter.Insert() with fewer Parameters

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I have a table `Users` with 3 columns `Id`, `Name`, `Address`.

I am using `usersTableAdapter.Insert()` for adding a new record, but it requires all 3 parameters including `Id` which is Identity column and `auto-incremented` and cannot be added manually.

Here is the code:

```
this.usersTableAdapter.Insert("Haroon", "Pakistan");
```

This is not working.

Is there any way to use the above command without providing an `Id` value?

Comment: Don't use a `TableAdapter`, but write your SQL `INSERT` statement yourself (`INSERT INTO Users(Name, Address) VALUES (@Name, @Address)`, and use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` to execute it

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you've set your tableadapter up incorrectly..

Examine this screenshot of a tableadapter conencted to a sql server table that has an autoincrement ID column. You can see the table design from SSMS in the to right (blue border). You can see highlighted that the table adapter was created with `select * from autoinctable` and the wizard has ONLY chosen to reference the `Text` column for INSERT (also highlighted)

[image]

In code, the Insert command only asks for the Text column:

[image]

This TA was created with "refresh the dataset" turned on; you can see in the commands (like insert) that the database calculated value is retrieved (`select ... scope_identity`)